# Where to find documentation of iOS8 Bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth

I'am developing an iOS Application which is part of my graduation project & part of this application is based on Bluetooth communication.

But as I am new to Swift and have zero experience about Objective-C, I tried to find out where the documentation of Core Bluetooth is.

What i found is Objective-C based code documentation. So could you please suggest me where i can find this documentation, or where I can start?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it at the same site [as the objective-c documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011295).

Just click on a class, protocol etc. Then, on the top right corner of the page you see a menu where you can choose the Language. So by choosing `Swift` you will see the documentation with Swift code.

Answer (score 0):

The apple developmer networks "[Bluetooth for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/bluetooth/)" section provides tons of resources including documents, videos and sample code.

Another good starting point is Ray Wenderlich's  ["Introduction to Core Bluetooth: Building a Heart Rate Monitor"](http://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor)